# Why doesn't Rails' "errors.full_messages" replace attribute and message variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, internationalization

Having a strange problem with a rails model I just created.

Here are my validations:

```
validates_presence_of :from_name, :message => 'Please provide a from name.'
validates_presence_of :from_email
validates_presence_of :giftition_plan_id
```

I'm having issues using `errors.full_messages` as well as `f.error_messages` in my form:

```
g = Giftition.create
g.errors.first
=> ["from_name", "Please provide a from name."]
>> g.errors.full_messages
=> ["{{attribute}} {{message}}", "{{attribute}} {{message}}", "{{attribute}} {{message}}"]
```

I'm just getting `"{{attribute}} {{message}}"`. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I've uninstalled rails 3 and all the gems that were installed with it and that made the problem go away. It's not a fix though... I would still like to have rails 3 installed.

UPDATE: Sounds like upgrading to 2.3.9 fixes the problem. Unfortunately, I've given up for now, but sometime in the future I will try that.

Comment: I just remembered I had just installed both rails 2.3.9 and 3.0.3... My googling says that definitely has something do with it... although I can find no fix.

Comment: Ruby, Gems and Rails should avoid problems with a conflict even if you have two versions installed. If you want to remove a version of Rails it's easy, though you want to be careful that you remove the version you are not using, or, upgrade to the 3.0+ if your project was 2.3.9, then do the removal. `gem uninstall rails -v 2.3.9`

Comment: i18n 0.5.0 was installed (as a dependency) when I installed the ancestry gem. I ended up with the issue you describe as I am running Rails 2.3.8. I was able to fix this issue by uninstalling i18n, and then reinstalling it but forcing version 0.4.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Upgrading to Version rails 2.3.9 fixes this problem

```
gem install -v 2.3.9 rails --include-dependencies
```

EDIT:

You also need to edit the `config\environment.rb` file to change the `RAILS_GEM_VERSION`.

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.9'
```

EDIT #2:

I should note that version 2.3.9 is not the latest version of the 2.3.X branch, and you should upgrade the the latest version available.

Comment: Same issue with Rails 2.3.5. I performed the update to 2.3.9 and it's now working as expected.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this problem as well with an old 2.3.5 Rails app that I inherited.  I had the 5.0 version of the i18n gem installed.  I saw that it needs the %{} syntax.  Doing this in config/locales/en.yml did the trick:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      full_messages:
        format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
```

Comment: Very nice! But now I still get things like: "{{count}} errors prohibited this {{model}} from being saved"

Comment: That sounds like an inherited resources issue. I did see that a few months back but unfortunately I don't recall the fix exactly. Assuming you have inherited resources in the mix, I'd look that direction.  Good luck!

Comment: @tybro0103: Me too has the same problem as you, Now I got fix. Check out your gem list for i18n gem and try after removing it than restart your application. Either go with i18n 0.4.0 version. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed locally by removing i18n-0.5.0.

experimenting with i18n-0.4.0 yields (while returning the correctly interpolated string):

```
The {{key}} interpolation syntax in I18n messages is deprecated. Please use %{key} instead.
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:160:in `interpolate_without_deprecated_syntax'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:155:in `gsub'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:155:in `interpolate_without_deprecated_syntax'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:188:in `preserve_encoding'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:154:in `interpolate_without_deprecated_syntax'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/i18n_interpolation_deprecation.rb:21:in `interpolate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:48:in `translate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n.rb:152:in `translate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:119:in `resolve'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:104:in `default'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:103:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:103:in `default'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:41:in `translate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.4.0/lib/i18n.rb:152:in `translate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in `generate_message'
```

I guess 0.5.0 turns up the pain by outputting non-interpolated strings.

---

i18n is required by activesupport, so the way I got around loading the most recent version (0.5.0) is:

in config/preinitializer.rb ('secret' lifecycle hook that loads before activesupport):

```
require 'rubygems'
begin
  gem 'i18n', "~> 0.4.0"
rescue LoadError
  # no biggie, optional anyway
end
```

Comment: I believe that was what "fixed" it for me as well, but notice "fixed" is in quotations.

Answer (score 1):

so i keep seeing upgrading rails as the solution to this

... or you can simply downgrade i18n to version 0.4

as outlined in this post

[getting {{attribute}} {{message}} in RoR views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720183/getting-attribute-message-in-ror-views/5275003#5275003)

Answer (score 1):

Go to dir_of_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.x/lib/active_record/locale and edit the en.yml... replace the {{variable}} to %{variable}

Worked for me...

PS: maybe the path would be different for you. Adapt for you convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a Rails 2.3.5 server at work that doesn't have i18n gem.   The odd thing is that while my code works locally, I have this problem on the work server.  And, another application I have with the same exact frozen gems does not display this problem on the work server.

I changed the activerecord en.yml file like above but also changed the actionpack en.yml file to get the error message title/header right:

```
   \vendor\rails\activerecord\lib\active_record\locale\en.yml

    #format: "{{attribute}} {{message}}"
     format: "%{attribute} %{message}"

    \vendor\rails\actionpack\lib\action_view\local\en.yml

      activerecord:
        errors:
          template:
            header:
              one:    "1 error prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
              other:  "%{count} errors prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
```

Also, I didn't bother with it but if you have error messages that contain counts, it looks like in the activerecord en.yml file you'd need to change the syntax of some of the messages too (like):

```
#too_long: "is too long (maximum is {{count}} characters)"
too_long: "is too long (maximum is #{count} characters)"
```

Comment: Does this technique require installing the entire Rails gem under 'vendor/', or can one just add the specific 'en.yml' files noted and they'll get picked up and override the standard Rails locale settings?

Answer (score 1):

```
cd <yourRailsProject> 
gem install i18n -v 0.4.0 -i vendor/ -V
```

to install the i18n gem into the vendor folder (-V for verbose output, just to see what's going on under the hood)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my complete config/locales/en.yml that solves the attribute, message, count, and model issues. I got this from the RoR docs here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      full_messages:
        format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
      template: 
        header:
          one: "1 error prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
          other: "%{count} errors prohibited this %{model} from being saved"