# I18n gem update causing error message crazyness in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, heroku, rubygems

This question is already here:

[Why doesn't Rails' "errors.full_messages" replace attribute and message variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370503/why-doesnt-rails-errors-full-messages-replace-attribute-and-message-variables)

... but it hasn't been answered yet and I am sure it's because of the gem I18n -version "0.5.0".

This error suddenly appeared for me and I'm just assuming it is because heroku is now using the latest gem version.

How can I get the whole application to use the previous version '0.4.1' or fix how the error messages without having to change the .yml or if I have to how would I setup the en.yml.

This is what is happening:

[image]

All error messages are now appearing like this with {{attribute}} {{message}} instead of the default which I would rather have.

Comment: I am having this problem as well, and I am actively working towards a solution. Will post back when I make some progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer to original question, [Why doesn't Rails' "errors.full_messages" replace attribute and message variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370503/why-doesnt-rails-errors-full-messages-replace-attribute-and-message-variables/4475246#4475246)

Comment: This one came out of the blue on me. 6 hours gone :(