# Rails 3 full error messages format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Since in Rails 3 form.error_messages is deprecated I'm using a partial in which I iterate over full_messages and structure my html like this:

```
<% model.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <p><%= msg %></p>
<% end %>
```

However the app's default locale is not English and in my language the structure of the full_messages is kinda unnatural:

```
{{attribute}} {{message}}
```

I saw from the source of generate_full_messages that I can localize the format and so in my locale's yml file (bg.yml) I added this:

```
bg:
 activerecord:
  errors:
   full_messages:
    format: "[...]"
```

However the format of the validation errors stays the same.

Comment: What format do you want?

Comment: The specifics is not important. I want it to start with a specific word then {{attribute}} {{message}} because without this word it sounds awkward in my language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

don't know if it can help, but a [locale file for Bulgarian is available on Github](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/bg.yml).

you may also try this (should work according to [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation)):

```
bg:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
    messages: &error_messages
      empty: "Something something %{attribute} something something"
```

[this blog post](http://www.taylorbrooks.org/error-messages-in-rails-attribute-message/) and this [stack overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370503/why-doesnt-rails-errors-full-messages-replace-attribute-and-message-variables) also talk about weird `{{attribute}} {{message}}` structures. Seems caused by a conflict between two I18n gems installed on the same server.

Answer (score 9):

Change your current code

```
<% @object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

With this

```
<% @object.errors.messages.values.each do |msg| %>
  <% msg.each do |m| %>
    <li><%= m %></li>
  <%end %>
<% end %>
```

And in your model customize the message:

```
validates :attribute, :presence => { :message => 'Attribute cannot be blank' }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Returns all the full error messages for a given attribute in an array.**

@object.errors.full_messages_for(:name)

=> ["Name is too short (minimum is 5 characters)", "Name can't be blank"]