# getting {{attribute}} {{message}} in RoR views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

Login
1 error prohibited this {{model}} from being saved

There were problems with the following fields:

- {{attribute}} {{message}}

this is the view code

```
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <% form_for @user_session, :url => user_session_path do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_messages %>
      <%= f.label :login %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :login %><br />
      <br />
      <%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %><br />
      <br />
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %><%= f.label :remember_me %><br />
      <br />
      <%= f.submit "Login" %>
    <% end %>
```

`
its odd and it shows up on in the time_ago_in_words method when the out put is in months

just kinda started doing this randomly, anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it happens when the version of Ruby has been upgraded to a version that is not supported by your version of Rails. Older version of rails uses a syntax that is not supported by newer versions of Ruby.

To solve it, you should either upgrade Rails or downgrade Ruby.

Rails 2.3.9 should be sufficient.

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/9/4/ruby-on-rails-2-3-9-released

Comment: ah ok, yeah that would make sense

Answer (score 6):

the i18n gem needs to correspond to the version of RUBY and RAILS that you're running ...

changelog for i18n.
http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2010/02/rails-3-i18n-changes/

running

`gem uninstall i18n`

then

```
gem install i18n -v 0.4.0
```

should solve any issues you've got with rails 2.3.8 and the double curly bracket error messages

Comment: This did the trick for me. Like Tom, I had installed the Money gem on a Rails 2.3.14 app and it was dependent on i18n. But it installed the latest version (6.x) of i18n. Downgrading i18n to 0.4.0 worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can also run into this if you install the i18n gem. I had installed metrical, and one of its dependencies is the i18n gem. This caused the same error as above. Once I removed the gem, I started seeing the correct messages again.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd <yourRailsProject> 
gem install i18n -v 0.4.0 -i vendor/ -V
```

to install the i18n gem into the vendor folder (-V for verbose output, just to see what's going on under the hood)